# Creating tooltips for SVG objects after they were translated and scaled

Tags: svg, d3.js, tooltip, transformation

I am trying to create SVG tooltip (simple DIVs) for SVG elements in my visualization. I use the D3 javascript library and I use the built-in D3 zoom behavior, which translates and scales the SVG objects. I would like to create tooltips right beside the SVG elements when clicking on them. The tooltips should move together with the SVG objects, but they should not be scaled by the mouswheel. Instead of that I would like to remove all of the tooltips on zoom-begin and recreate them after the zooming is over.

I get it working, but I still have problems. The position for the tooltips is computed ok, even if they are scaled. I can also move them along the screen with the SVG objects. The problem is if I move the SVG object with the mouse first, create an tooltip and move the SVG object one again. The tooltips jumps then. I also can not remove them on zoom-start and recreate on zoom-finished.

Here is a little example showing my approach :

```
var tooltipCounter = 0;

var  svgElement = d3.select('body')
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr('width', '100%')
    .attr('height', '100%');

var container = svgElement.append('svg:g');

var circle = container.append('svg:circle')
    //.attr('cx', 100)
    //.attr('cy', 100)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(100,100)')
    .attr('r', 30)
    .attr('fill', 'red')
    .on('click', createTooltip);

svgElement.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom', redrawOnZoom));

 function redrawOnZoom(){
    container.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.translate + ')' + ' scale(' +         d3.event.scale + ')')
    var tooltips = $("[id$=tooltip] ");
    for (var i=0; i<tooltips.length; i++) {
        var tooltip = tooltips[i];
        tooltip.style['-webkit-transform'] = "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0] + "px," +  d3.event.translate[1] + "px)"
    }
};

function createTooltip(){
    tooltipCounter ++
    var tooltipId = tooltipCounter + '_tooltip'
    // get the transformation matrix of the circle
    var transMat = circle[0][0].getCTM();
    var x = transMat.e;
    var y = transMat.f;
    var scale = transMat.d; 
    var radius = parseInt(circle.attr('r'))

    var margin = parseInt(d3.select('body').style('margin'))

    var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('xhtml:div')
        .attr('id', tooltipId)
        .style('position', 'absolute')
        .style('background', 'gray')
        .style('left', x + (scale * radius) + margin + 'px')     
        .style('top', y + (scale * radius/2) + margin + 'px')
        .html('<- This is tooltip.');

}
```

Here is a working JsFiddle code : http://jsfiddle.net/HzBQg/

EDIT :

I managed to detect the scrolling/scaling by comparing the current scale-value of the container with the scale value of the zoom-event. Not sure if this is the best way, but it works and I can remove all of the tooltips when the scroll-wheel is moved. I still do not know how to recreate them after the zoom-behavior is over. And I still have problems when creating the tooltips after the SVG object was moved.

Updated JsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/HzBQg/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problems, although the solution is not perfect it works.

```
var dx = d3.event.translate[0] - container[0][0].getCTM().e;
var dy = d3.event.translate[1] - container[0][0].getCTM().f;

container.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.translate + ')' + ' scale(' + d3.event.scale + ')')
var tooltips = $("[id$=tooltip] ");
    for (var i=0; i<tooltips.length; i++) {
        var tooltip = tooltips[i];
        if (scrolling){
            tooltip.parentNode.removeChild(tooltip)
        }
        else{
            tooltipTransMat = $('#'+tooltip.id).css("-webkit-transform").match(/(-?[0-9\.]+)/g);
            tooltip.style['-webkit-transform'] = "translate(" + (parseFloat(tooltipTransMat[4])+dx) + "px," + (parseFloat(tooltipTransMat[5])+dy) + "px)"
        }
    }
```

You can see it in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/HzBQg/3/